# Issue installing ReactiveCocoa 3.0.0-alpha.1 in iOS 8.0 project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I've added ReactiveCocoa to my Podfile and successfully installed. However, when I try to build my project I get a problem to do with "Create static library for libPods-LlamaKit.a"

Looks as though LLamaKit is written in Swift (whereas my project is ObjC) - does this matter?

The error given is:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
```

Comment: @ThomasKilian don't think Apple would have much interest in a third party library?

Comment: ups. I've heard about ReactiveCocoa and assumed it was some new derivate from Apple :-[ So you should probably contact the open source community.

Comment: Are you using the beta version of CocoaPods?

Comment: @KeithSmiley On pod version 0.34.4

Comment: Same problem I'm experiencing as well. Would love to get around this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the new 3.0.0 alpha of ReactiveCocoa is written in Swift. Swift is not yet supported by CocoaPods in the release builds (see [this blog post](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/)). If you'd like you can installed the beta version of CocoaPods to solve this problem.

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Otherwise you'll have to wait till the official release. If you don't want to use that beta version you should check out [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). Carthage has a similar purpose to CocoaPods and it is written by the same people who wrote ReactiveCocoa.

Comment: I got around to doing this shortly after I posted and I can confirm that it works.

Comment: One question. If I use Carthage, then I can't use my project for iOS 7. Am I right? Thanks